# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' even though module exists

Tags: python, linux

I have trouble with python module "requests" on Linux env. I have python 3.6 installed on this linux server. Unix admin confirmed that requets module has been installed on this server. This is how I am checking if module is already installed or not. I can see request module exists.

```
$ source /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
$  pip show request
Name: request
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: http REQUEST (GET+POST) dict
Home-page: https://github.com/looking-for-a-job/request.py
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: get, post, setuptools
Required-by:
```

But when I try to run python code, i still get this error.

```
import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

What am I missing here? Any help?

Comment: How are you invoking python?

Comment: Also, you showed the output of `pip show request`, but the package is called `requests`. What does `pip show requests` show?

Comment: Just to confirm... you meant to say "requests" instead of "request" in `pip show request`, correct? That's just a typo? `request` from `https://github.com/looking-for-a-job/request.py` is completely different from the actual `requests` library.

Comment: `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`

Comment: oops.. so unix admin installed request module. i didnt realize 's' at the end. when i run the command pip show request it shows nothing. I guess this must be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If `/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages` is not shown in `sys.path`, you have several options.

1. Install the package in the `site-packages` directory that shows up in your `sys.path`. You can change the install location with `pip install --target=/somewhere/else package_name`
2. Move the existing package to the `site-packages` directory that shows up in your `sys.path`.
3. Add the directory to your `sys.path` by running `sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages')` in Python.